# Default category for taxonomy in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a taxonomy category called "event status" and I was wondering if at all possible, if you could make one of the categories set to default like posts has with it's category section? For instance I want to make "Current" the default category.

The code I have is:

```
function register_business_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy('event_status',array('events'),array(
    'label' => 'Event Status',
    'public'=>true,
    'hierarchical'=>true,
    'show_ui'=>true,
    'query_var'=>true
));
```

}

Would I need to write a function to do this?

Comment: Looks like I've found the answer, unfortunately custom status's in wordpress aren't viewable by the public unless they are logged in.